# Finding equivalent resistance of a complex circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I have a problem which asks for finding equivalent resistance of a circuit which
cannot be simplified to a simpler circuit by mere observation.

[image]

I tried to solve it by simplifying series resistance and then passing current through A and B to apply for Kirchoff's 2nd law.

[image]

**Loop 1**

$$i_2+2i_4=0$$

**Loop 2**

$$2i+5i_2=0 $$

**Loop 3**

$$ i_1+2i_4=0$$

**Loop 4**

$$i+5i_1+5i_4=0$$
I ended with some equations but I cannot solve from here as I think this is a very long method and there must be some short method for this problem. I want help in further solution of the problem.

Comment: Ignore the 10 ohms resistor for the moment and see if you can simplify the rest.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Comment: Redraw the circuit after labelling points of equal potential. You don't really require Kirchoff's law

Comment: @DrChuck Your hint really helped me ,I made an observation that all the three remaining resistance are in parallel ,but I still cannot figure out the exact reason for parallel arrangement.

Comment: Pranjal - if you do as @thewitness suggests, that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Potential at point A is 0,therefore V2=0,because there is no resistance through point A and V2.